# Simplifying symbolic multiple sums

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

suppose I have  a multiple sum with an unspecified number of indexes:

$$\sum_{i_1=1}^n \ldots \sum_{i_k=1}^n x_{i_1}\otimes\ldots\otimes \hat{x_{i_j}}\otimes\ldots\otimes x_{i_k}$$

with $x_{i_j}$ being omitted in the sum. The number $n$ is a positive integer. We can simplify this expression to
$$n \sum_{i_1=1}^n \ldots \sum_{i_{k-1}=1}^n x_{i_1}\otimes\ldots\otimes x_{i_{k-1}},$$

but my frail attempts at teaching this to Mathematica 6 have tremendously failed. It won't accept any pattern of type

```
Sum[x_, y___, {k_, l_, m_}, z___] /; FreeQ[x, k] :> (m - l) Sum[x, y, z].
```

complaining about `y___` not being an iterator.

Please help :)

Comment: Do you know the function `HoldPattern`?

Comment: Now, I do, thanks :)

Comment: [This Link](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/3336/) can also be useful.